# How to give a timeout between a set of ajax calls?

Tags: ajax, settimeout, intervals, rotten-tomatoes

I have a Rotten Tomatoes API limit of 10 calls/second. I need to make 50 calls in total.

If I make them all together many calls are getting rejected.

So I need to give a timeout of 1 second after I make every 10 calls.

How do I implement this ? Here's my code:

```
$.get("t250.txt", function (data) {
    var elem = data.split("\n");
    $.each(elem, function(index, item) {
        var $placeholder = $('<div>').appendTo("div.content");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(item) + '&page_limit=1',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                async: false,
                success: searchCallback
            });
        }, 1000);

        function searchCallback(data){});
    }
}
```

The problem still persists. Moreover the page waits for 1 second to load and then loads everything altogether. I have given the `setTimeout` function inside a for each loop. There seems to be no effect due to that. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Elem comes from a text file . I have updated the code for your reference.

Comment: Where is the 10 calls per second logic? If you loop through all your elements in your .each(), you will have created 50 timeouts that all trigger somewhat simultaneously after 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `async: false` in `$.ajax()`.

**Edit:**
Try this:

```
var elem;
var timeoutId;
function getURLs(){
    $.get("t250.txt", function (data) {
        elem = data.split("\n");
    });

    timeoutId = setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);    
}

var idx = 0;
function sendRequest(){
    if (idx > elem.length-1){
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        return;
    }
    var item = elem[idx];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(item) + '&page_limit=1',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: searchCallback
        });
    idx++;   
}

function searchCallback(data) {
//Callback logic
}
```

Comment: I did. No effect. I get the first 10 movies, then the next 10 movies gets lost , i get the next 10 . Each call didnt seem to get delayed by 1 second .

Comment: Just tried it out. Nothing turns up in the screen. I am doing some basic thing wrong. Couldnt figure out which one. Here's a JS Fiddle containing this code. Kindly check it out . http://jsfiddle.net/ZdyfN/